# Updating v2 to v3 Google maps API Not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been given the task to update our API call from v2 to v3 and heres the code it's rendering. However the returned google map is just a blank space, so clearly i'm doing something wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=fakekey&sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad(xLat,yLong,strAddress,mapname) {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapname));


        //map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
         alert(xLat);
            var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(xLat,yLong);

        var point = new google.maps.Point(xLat,yLong);

        // Create a marker whose info window displays the given number.
        function createMarker(point, number, strMessage) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point);


        // Show this marker's index in the info window when it is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(strMessage);
        });

        return marker;
        }

        var marker = createMarker(point, 1, strAddress);
        marker.setMap(map);

        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3
:)
Regards
-Vitor

Comment: Thanks, but i've read that and I can't work out what is wrong.

Comment: I've already passed through that. The documentation is really poor :/

Answer (score 0):

1. In v2 Point and LatLng were sometimes used interchangeably. Use google.maps.LatLng for geographic coordinates
2. You need to provide options to initialize the center, zoom, and type of the map.
3. marker.openInfoWindow is a v2 method, you need to replace that with the [v3 equivalent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).
4. your syntax for the google.maps.Marker constructor is incorrect, it takes a [MarkersOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function onLoad(xLat,yLong,strAddress,mapname) {
     var initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(xLat,yLong);
     var mapOptions = {center: initialLocation,
                       zoom: 8,
                       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                      };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapname), mapOptions);
     var marker = createMarker(map, initialLocation, 1, strAddress);
     marker.setMap(map);
   }
   function createMarker(map, point, number, strMessage) {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point});
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
     // Show this marker's index in the info window when it is clicked.
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.setContent(strMessage);
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });

     return marker;
   }

   </script>
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. I still only get a white square when I run it though